# Show count with Facebook Like icon

Tags: asp.net, facebook

In my web form, I have to show count of likes, just like it happens in Facebook. For that I am using below html code in a frame.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" 
style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 260px; height: 35px;"            
 src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=139756762768973&amp;
 href&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp; 
 show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&        
 amp;height=35"></iframe>
```

When the page gets rendered, it shows you a Like icon, on clicking the icon it will open the facebook pop up to input your credentials. Now i want to show the count of likes parallel to the like icon.

Any help will be really very appreciated...

Comment: Your question might get a better response at webmasters.stackexchange.com. This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: ok. I need to just show the count on my page using it. If you are talking about the basic understanding of how to accomplish it and in order to do that I should move it there then Please migrate it...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using wrong URL in the IFrame

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good way to use this plugin, and because of that you have no control over how the button is rendered.

You should use the code you get here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/, it uses the facebook javascript sdk, and in that page you can play with the different options to get the most suitable design for the button (from what fb let you play with).

You might also want to check another like widget: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Comment: can you help me out to show just the count along with Like button please ?

Comment: those are not articles but the official documentation, I suggest that you get familiar with that.  Also, if this answers your question, please mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Really?  this is hardly a question for this place.  It's very straight forward how to use the form in that page, all you have to do is uncheck some boxes (like the "Send Button" and "Show Faces") and you see the result, right there.

Comment: I tried with the below code and it is enabling the like button on clicking it and on the other hand in link it is not behaving in this way...

Comment: <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21"
            scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 450px;
            height: 21px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>

Comment: why do you write the iframe yourself instead of using the code they provide you with the js sdk?  When you click the "Get Code" button you are presented with 3 options: HTML5, XFBML and IFRAME, if you click the iframe one it says "This plugin does not have an iframe implementation with the selected options. Please use the JavaScript SDK and the HTML5 or XFBML implementations, or change the value of the send parameter." doesn't this tell you that it's not the right way to go?  Just try either the HTML5 or the XFBML

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7760/discussion-between-pankaj-garg-and-nitzan-tomer)

Comment: I am doing in the same way. clicking the GetCode button and selection third option i.e. IFrame

Comment: My side it is showing me the IFrame code... as mentioned above.

Comment: no, i said do **not** use the iframe option, it even says so in the facebook place to get the code, i quoted that for in my last response. use one of the **other** methods (html5 or xhtml)